# How to compare two strings of a file match the strings of another file using AWK?

Tags: awk

I possess 2 huge files and I need to count how many entries of file 1 exist on file 2.

The file 1 contains two ids, source and destination, like below:

```
11111111111111|22222222222222
33333333333333|44444444444444
55555555555555|66666666666666
11111111111111|44444444444444
77777777777777|22222222222222
44444444444444|00000000000000
12121212121212|77777777777777
01010101010101|01230123012301
77777777777777|97697697697697
66666666666666|12121212121212
```

The file 2 contains the valid id list, which will be used to filter file 1:

```
11111111111111
22222222222222
44444444444444
77777777777777
00000000000000
88888888888888
66666666666666
99999999999999
12121212121212
01010101010101
```

What I am struggling to achieve is find a way to count how many entries in file one possess the entry in file 2.  Only when both numbers in the same line
exist in file 2 will the line be counted.

On file 2:

`11111111111111|22222222222222` — This will be counted because both entries exist on file 2, as well as `77777777777777|22222222222222` because both entries exist on file 2.

`33333333333333|44444444444444` — This will not be counted because `33333333333333` does not exist on file 2 and the same goes to `55555555555555|66666666666666`, the first does not exist on file 2.

So in the examples I mentioned in the beginning it should count 6, and printing this should be enough, better than editing one file.

Comment: It wouldn't be a bad idea to identify how big your 'huge' files are.  Is that 100 KiB, 1 MiB, 10 MiB, 100 MiB, 1 GiB, bigger?  And are you on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine?  How much memory?  My suspicion is that your huge files are under 1 GiB and you'll have 4 GiB or more memory in your machine, in which case there aren't going to be many problems.  But if you're actually dealing with 10 TiB of data in File 1 and 1 PiB of data in file 2, then the problem is more complex.

Comment: In the file 1, each file has more than 3 million entries. And the other file has about the same size. But file 1 has about 80mb and file 2 50mb.
I running this on Cent OS 32bits, 16 GB ram.

Comment: OK; those are pretty big, but they'll fit in memory well enough.  I'm intrigued that `file2` contains 250 MiB but only one column, while `file1` contains 80 MiB and two columns — that must mean there are a lot more lines in `file2` than in `file1`.  If the row size shown is about right, then about 15 bytes per entry and 250 MiB means over 16 million entries, whereas 30 bytes per entry and 80 MiB means about 3 million entries as you said.  Are you sure you didn't reverse the sizes?  Your machine is going to be creaking a bit — it would be more comfortable if you were running in 64-bit mode.

Comment: File two is a list of all valid user and last time I took the data it had more than 15 million entries, for that reason it it bigger.  But I split in different files, split by are, so I will have about 9 files with an average of 1.8 million lines.
It will be faster to run.
I just thank everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR == NR { seen[$0] = 1; next }
           seen[$1] && seen[$2] { ++count }
           END { print count }' file2 file1
```

Explanation:

1) `FNR == NR` (number of record in current file equals number of record) is only true for the first input file, which is `file2` (the order is important!). Thus for every line of `file2`, we record the number in `seen`.

2) For other lines (which is `file1`, given second on the command line) if the `|`-separated fields (`-F'|'`) number 1 and 2 were both `seen` (in `file2`), we increment `count` by one.

3) In the `END` output the `count`.

Caveat: Every unique number in `file2` is loaded into memory. But this also makes it fast instead of having to read through `file2` over and over again.

Comment: The `**` was intended to be 'bold' Markdown, but the data was reformatted.  Your `gsub` is not going to do any harm, but with the revised data, it isn't going to do any good either (and will slow things down somewhat).  Otherwise, just what the OP requested.

Comment: @YagamiSama Glad it worked for you. Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. =)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do it in `awk` but if you are open to a quick-and-dirty bash script that someone can help make efficient, you could try this:

```
searcher.sh
-------------
#!/bin/bash

file1="$1"
file2="$2"

-- split by pipe
while IFS='|' read -ra line; do

    -- find 1st item in file2. If found, find 2nd item in file2 
    grep -q ${line[0]} "$file2"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

        grep -q ${line[1]} "$file2"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

            -- print line since both items were found in file2
            echo "${line[0]}|${line[1]}"

        fi

    fi

done < "$file1"

Usage
------
bash searcher.sh file1 file2

Result using your example
--------------------------
$ time bash searcher.sh file1 file2
11111111111111 | 22222222222222
11111111111111 | 44444444444444
77777777777777 | 22222222222222
44444444444444 | 00000000000000
12121212121212 | 77777777777777
66666666666666 | 12121212121212

real    0m1.453s
user    0m0.423s
sys     0m0.627s
```

That's really slow on my old PC.

Comment: As a general comment, you don't need to do `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` after each `grep`, you can just directly use `if grep -q …; then`.

Comment: That was also a good one better than mine. But AWK is way faster :  real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s   while your script took about 1 sec.